# Spider не забирает данные:

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Вот код:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

class DjiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dji"
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"]




    def parse_item(self, response):
        books = response.css('article.product_pod')
        for book in books:
            yield{
                'name':book.css('h3 a::text').get(),
            }
```

И вывод:

```
2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.9.0 started (bot: dron)
2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.12, 
cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.8.1, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.10.11 
(tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 
23.2.0 (OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023), cryptography 41.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.22621- 


 SP0
   2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
    {'BOT_NAME': 'dron',
     'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
     'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'dron.spiders',
     'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
     'SPIDER_MODULES': ['dron.spiders'],
     'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: 
    twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: 
    asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: f660c2590cd13e3d
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
    ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
     'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
     'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
    ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
    ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
    []
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), 
    scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2023-07-06 23:05:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 
    127.0.0.1:6023
    2023-07-06 23:05:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
    https://books.toscrape.com/> (referer: None)
    2023-07-06 23:05:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
    2023-07-06 23:05:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 218,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 51555,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.832265,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 6, 20, 5, 19, 773400),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
     'log_count/INFO': 10,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 6, 20, 5, 18, 941135)}
    2023-07-06 23:05:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: "Spider не забирает данные" - это констатация факта. А вопрос мы должны домыслить вместо вас сами?